# How to do POST/GET request in python?

Tags: android, python

I have a python server which parses a HTML page, the script runs fine. However I have an android application which will call this server by sending an argument i.e. a URL.

I want the server to get the URL posted by the android application and parse the data of the HTML page.

My queries are :- Which method should I use ?
                    **GET** or **POST**

I have gone through tutorials and I think it is the POST method.

Below is my script/server which I made. Kindly suggest me what edits should be done.

```
import cherrypy
import ConfigParser
import json
import mimetypes
import os
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urlparse
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import SocketServer

########################################################################
details_array=[]
small_details_array=[]
price_cell_array=[]
lst = []
URL_path

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
         self._set_headers()
         URL_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
         request_id = URL_path.path

    def do_POST(self):
        self._set_headers()
        URL_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
        request_id = URL_path.path


r  = requests.get(URL_path)#the URL_path holds the URL
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table',{'class':'table'})
s=""

targetFile=open("plist","w")
detailtext = table.findAll('div',{'class':'detailtext'})
for det in detailtext:

        details_array.append(det.text)

smalldetails = table.findAll('div',{'style':'padding-top:5px'})

for smallDet in smalldetails:

        small_details_array.append(smallDet.text);


price_cells = table.findAll('td', {'class': 'pricecell'})
for price_cell in price_cells:
    price_cell_array.append(price_cell.text)


for i in range(len(details_array)):
        d_arr = {}
        d_arr['detail']=details_array[i]
        temp = small_details_array[i].split('\n')
        d_arr['talktime'] = temp[1] 
        d_arr['keyword']=temp[3]
        tempnew = price_cell_array[i].split('\n')
        d_arr['price'] = tempnew[1]
        d_arr['validity'] = tempnew[3]
        # global list
        lst.append(d_arr)

t_arr={}
t_arr['events'] = lst;
print json.dumps(t_arr)
targetFile.write("[TopUpList]"+"\n"+"events=")
targetFile.write(json.dumps(t_arr))
targetFile.write('\n[culturalEvents]\nevents={"events": [{"venue": "bangalore", "name": "Culttest"}]}')
targetFile.close()
#########################################################################

class Server():

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        return "Seems Like You're Lost :D"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def eventsList(self,choice):

        message="Success, Event List Obtained"
        status_code=0;
        events=[]
        try:
            if choice.title() == "Cultural":
                events = cultural_event_list['events']
            elif choice.title() == "Prodlisting":
                events = lists['events']
            else:
                status_code=-1
                message="Failed, No Such Event Type Enlisted"
        except:
                status_code=-1
                message="Failed, Server Error! Error Occured while retreiving Event List"
        return json.dumps({'status_code':status_code,'message':message,'events':events})

    @cherrypy.expose
    def eventsStatus(self,choice):

        message="Success, Event List Obtained"
        status_code=0;
        events=[]
        try:

            if choice.title() == "Cultural":
                events = cultural_event_list['events']
            elif choice.title() == "Prodlisting":
                events = lists['events']
            else:
                status_code=-1
                message="Failed, No Such Event Type Enlisted"
        except:
                status_code=-1
                message="Failed, Server Error! Error Occured while retreiving Event List"
        return json.dumps({'status_code':status_code,'message':message,'hash':json.dumps(events).__hash__()})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' Setting up the Server with Specified Configuration'''
    '''
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('server.conf')
    cherrypy.server.socket_host = config.get('server','host')
    cherrypy.server.socket_port = int(config.get('server','port'))
    cherrypy.server.socket_host = '127.0.0.1'
    cherrypy.server.socket_port = 5000
    '''

    list = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',})
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000')),})
    list.read('plist')#the file from where it reads
    lists=json.loads(list.get('TopUpList','events'))
    cultural_event_list=json.loads(list.get('culturalEvents','events'))

cherrypy.quickstart(Server())
```

P.S. I think the android part needs a POST request to be sent to the python server, kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

GET - Requests data from a specified resource
POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

So if you want to submit data, use POST

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 0):

Based on conclusion that you just want to get some information without updating anything on server side I can tell that GET request will be enough and theoretically more idiomatically.

So you just should make request with URL like www.yourdomain.com/?q=domaintocrawl.com and get parsed data in response.